# Running powershell script from python code

Tags: python, powershell

I need to run a PowerShell script from python code on Windows. I have python installed and I have setup the environment variables.

I tried `subprocess.call` as well, but nothing is working for me. I get the error:

> io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

**Python code**

```
import subprocess , sys

p = subprocess.Popen
(["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.ps1"])
p.communicate()
```

**PowerShell test.ps1**

```
Write-Host ("swan is awesome") 
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "xxxx"
```

Comment: You will need to elaborate more on "nothing is working"

Comment: can you try with `check_output` instead of `Popen` ? in that case that would get you the output as a return value, and not the process (that you don't need), and an exception if it doesn't work properly

Comment: I tried check_output, shows error subprocess.CalledProcessError

Comment: `"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.ps1"` seems unlikely that your username is "Desktop" and the powershell file is in the root of your user folder. But apart from that, your code runs without error for me in Python 2.7, whether the PS1 exists or not, whether I have permission to create a New-Item in the path or not.

Comment: How come its a valid path for you -- "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.ps1"..

There should be a user corresponding to that path

Answer (score 0):

Your are not capturing the program output, while spawing a new process you can give something like this `subprocess([],stdout=sys.stdout)`